# Setting global styles for elements in tkz-euclide

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-euclide

Is is possible to set global styles for elements when using tkz-euclide? (I have a document with many TikZ figures in it and I want to be able to set different styles for different groups of lines, points, etc., which can be controlled by changing parameters at the top of the file.)

It is possible to do this in TikZ using `\tikzset`, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this when using tkz-euclide.

Here is a minimal example which I hope will help explain what I am trying to do:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,fullpage}
\usetkzobj{all}

 \tikzset{%
  mystyleone/.style={%
 color=blue!50!white,
 fill=gray!20!red!50!white
               }      
  mystyletwo/.style={%
  color=blue!70!black,
  fill=blue!70!black
   }
  }

  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
  \tkzClip

   % Set out the initial points
   \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
    \tkzDefPoint(0,1){A} 

   \tkzDrawPoints[mystyleone](O)
   \tkzDrawPoints[mystyletwo](A)

   % labels
   \tkzLabelPoints(O,A)

   \end{tikzpicture}

  \end{document}
```

As shown in this example, I would like to be able to define some style variables, and then call them in with a single name as an option in `\tkzDrawCircle`, `\tkzDrawSegments`, `\tkzLabelPoints`, etc.

Comment: Short answer: no. For settings for all nodes, as far i was able to figured out from french manual, is defined ``\tkzSetUpPoint``, which should be present in each picture. Exception from this setting should be defined locally.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is entirely what you're after, but I'm posting it as an answer for now because I had to correct other parts of your code for this to work, so it's easiest to show this way. I'll delete the answer if this is not an acceptable solution.

A quick way to make this work as you're expecting is to simply put the full path of the key (for your case, `/tikz/mystyleone`) in the option setting. This is required because `tkz-euclide` `.cd`s (`c`hanges `d`irectory) into a different localized key path for each of the commands `\tkzDrawCircle`, `\tkzDrawPoints`, etc. We need to put the full path of the user-defined style to "escape" from this narrowed key search path.

Here's the full code after correcting the style definitions so both are found:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[upright]{fourier} 
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,fullpage}
%\usetkzobj{all} % useless with the new version

\tikzset{
  mystyleone/.style={
    color=blue!50!white,
    fill=gray!20!red!50!white,
  },
  mystyletwo/.style={
    color=blue!70!black,
    fill=blue!70!black,
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tkzInit[xmin=-4,xmax=4,ymin=-4,ymax=4]
  \tkzClip

  % Set out the initial points
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,1){A} 

  \tkzDrawPoints[/tikz/mystyleone](O)
  \tkzDrawPoints[/tikz/mystyletwo](A)

  % labels
  \tkzLabelPoints(O,A) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image]

Comment: I'm glad that I was wrong in my comment :-)

Answer (score 2):

The good way is something between Darko's comment and Paul's answer.

In principle in classical figures only one style of points is used.
This must be defined with `\tkzSetUpPoint` then you have the possibility to define your own style but like this :

`\tikzset{/tikz/mystyletwo/.style={color=blue!20!black,fill=blue!20}}`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
%\usetkzobj{all} % useless with the new version
\tkzSetUpPoint[color=blue!50!white, fill=gray!20!red!50!white] 
\tikzset{/tikz/mystyletwo/.style={ color=blue!20!black, fill=blue!20}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Set out the initial points
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){O}
  \tkzDefPoint(0,1){A} 
  % drawing
  \tkzDrawPoints(O)
  \tkzDrawPoints[mystyletwo,size=4](A)
  % labels
  \tkzLabelPoints(O,A) 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]